# Bumper Impact bar bolt resuse on trailer hitch - 2014 Audi Q7

Tags: audi, trailer-hitch

I purchased [curt trailer hitch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007M1I2A) for my 2014 Audi Q7. I had to first remove the bumper impact bar which comes factory installed. In place of bumper impact bar, the trailer hitch is supposed to fit perfectly. It actually fit perfectly. However the bolts that came with curt trailer hitch were too long to fit in fully. So I ended reusing the bolts that came out of the bumper impact bar. My question is - are the bumper impact bar bolts safe enough to be used on trailer hitch. Will bumper impact bar bolts be able to withstand very heavy loads which curt trailer hitch can carry. Or should I replace these with bolts that can withstand load on trailer hitch. The bumper impact bar bolts color is silverish and the ones that came with curt trailer hitch had golden/yellow color on it

Comment: Check the markings on the heads of the bolts - that will give you the grade.. and therefore load capacity.

Comment: Personally, I would contact the hitch manufacturer and have them provide the correct bolts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The impact bar has M12x1.5 bolt of 50mm length and Grade 8 (8.8) . The bolts that came with hitch receiver are grade 10 (10.9). So the conclusion is I cannot use the bolts from Impact bar because grade 8 is less strength than grade 10. Check [this link](https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/materials-and-grades/bolt-grade-chart.aspx) for info on bolt grades . I ordered M12x10.5x50 bolts of grade 10 online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the bolts should work just fine.

The bolts were providing enough support for the bumper impact bar and would be expected to hold up to a collision/impact without failure ... there's no reason to believe they won't do the same for the hitch. As long as you've torqued them down, they should easily be able to hold the hitch.

Comment: This is not about just holding the hitch. This is about holding the hitch and then towing a trailer.

Comment: @msgboardpana - That was my meaning. This should not be an issue. If the hitch was made to haul the load, the bolts are more than capable of holding the tow hitch to the vehicle.

Comment: Hmm, the bumper impact bar is subject to an impact so the bolts are not put under a tension load, while with a tow hitch they will be under tension when the tow hitch is being used...

Comment: @SolarMike - Yes, but they *would be under tension* if the bar was hit. The bolts have to survive this, which could be far worse than what having the trailer hitch on there would be while being used. BTW, all bolts when affixed and tightened are under tension.

Comment: They might be under shear if the bar bends,  most bumper bars are held on by the bolts acting in tension as you point out and that is the direction of the force applied to the bumper bar which won't increase the tension on the bolt...

Comment: @SolarMike - And they won't be in sheer because there's a little thing called friction between the tow hitch and the frame. Just like wheels on the hub, it's the not the lugs (or bolts in this case) which keeps wheel from spinning on the hub (even if it would be a minute amount), it's the friction between the wheel and the hub which keeps it from spinning. The lug just provides the clamping force to keep them in place. Also, the tow hitch is designed (when loaded correctly) not to flex or bend, this prevents damage to the frame.

Comment: Tow hitches do flex - and at Uni, one of the tasks I was involved with was testing a new design of tow hitch on a cyclic testing machine to see how / when it failed : somewhere over 3 million cycles...

Comment: Perhaps you should draw a force diagram and work out where the friction is applied and the shear as well...

Comment: the force that an impact bar and its screws is supposed to withstand is entirely different and in opposite direction (almost always) to the force that a trailer hitch and screws holding it are supposed to withstand.  Unfortunately I did not get a proper answer :(

Comment: @msgboardpana - What is the size and grade of the bolts?